# jQuery: Find array items in text string

Tags: jquery, arrays, match

How can I find array items in a text string?

I don't know the array and I don't know the text. But when an array item is contained in the text then party!

```
var arrayString = 'apple | ape | soap',
    text = "This a nice apple tree.";

var array = arrayString.split(" | ");

var matchedArrayItem = "..."; // please help on this

if(matchedArrayItem) {
    $("body").append('The text contains the array item "'+ matchedArrayItem +'".');
}
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/9RxvM/

Comment: regex should match something like /\b(apple|ape|tree)\b/ - you do not need jQuery here at all

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789945/how-can-i-check-if-one-string-contains-another-substring-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use JavaScript `search(str)`.

```
var matchedArrayItem = "";
for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    if(text.search(array[i])!=-1){
         matchedArrayItem = array[i];
         break;
    }
}

if(matchedArrayItem!="") {
    $("body").append('The text contains the array item "'+ matchedArrayItem +'".');
}
```

Note that this will get the first matched item in the array.
To check if there is a matched item, just check if matchedArrayItem!="";

Comment: How could I run this for multiple matches and replace the text output and array string? http://jsfiddle.net/9RxvM/4/

Answer (score 1):

One way with Regex:

```
var arrayString = 'apple|ape|soap',
  text = "This a nice apple tree.";

var matchedArrayItem = text.match(new RegExp("\\b(" + arrayString + ")\\b"));

if(matchedArrayItem) {
    $("body").append('The text contains the array item "'+ matchedArrayItem[0] +'".');
}

$("body").append("<br><br>" + arrayString + "<br>" + text);
```

Note: I removed the spaces from the array string to make it the correct format

Note2: `match()` returns an array of matches, so I take the first (`[0]`) result.

http://jsfiddle.net/9RxvM/2/